# Directed graph to visualize a python library's functions/classes

Tags: python

I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to quickly/automatically generate a directed graph (nodes/edges web) to visualize how the class types and functions of a given Python library are organized.

I find that some libraries that are essentially wrappers for a website's API tend to have a (necessarily) convoluted structure of classes and functions that may connect back to one another and I end up building a directed graph with something like draw.io to better see how one class connects to another. **Is there a way I could get Python to do this for me for any library I'm interested in?**

Comment: I don't know any library, but it seems to me like a simple recursive calls to something that uses `dir()` might be your friend here. Keep in might though, not every method might be accessible/visible before calling the `__init__()` of a class. If you want to see internal connections, you might have to look through the code with `ast` module.

Comment: Thanks a million for the reference to `dir()`!! I guess it was a basic part of Python that somehow slipped through the cracks for me. Very helpful.